# Inject jndi string resource on embedded glassfish using CDI not working

Tags: cdi, glassfish-embedded

So I created a custom reference in the domain.xml

```
<custom-resource res-type="java.lang.String" jndi-name="jndi/myResource" factory-class="org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PrimitivesAndStringFactory">
        <property name="value" value="myValue"/>
</custom-resource>
```

And referencing it through `@Resource(lookup = "jndi/myResource")` in a @ApplicationScoped bean.

I am also starting the server with the endorsed directory(containing the endorsed-api.jar). Still when I reference the resource, its not injecting and throwing a null.

Looks like everything is setup correctly, not sure what I am missing here.
And yes, I have beans.xml in the Meta-inf directory too.

Comment: Did you try lookup = "java:comp/env/jndi/myResource"?

Comment: yep, that didnt help either.